# Closed subsets of compact sets are compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

If S is a compact subset of R and T is a closed subset of S,then T is compact.
(1) Prove this using the definition of compactness.

Can somebody   prove it? I think we should select a open cover of S randomly, and then we should think about the set S-T. Is S-T open in R? I don't know how to continue?

Comment: It doesn't matter if $S-T$ is open in $R$. The definition of compactness is internal: A topological space $X$ is compact if any cover of $X$ by sets which are open _in $X$_ contains an open subcover of $X$.

Comment: what can you say about $\lbrace T^c \rbrace \cup \lbrace U_n ;\,n\in {\rm I\!N\,}\rbrace$ where   $(U_i)_{\scriptsize {i \in I}}$ a family of open (open for the topology of S) whose union contains S?

Comment: Next time please choose a more descriptive title for your question.

Comment: I know S-T is open in S, but Why R-T is open ?

Comment: What is the definition of a closed set in $\Bbb R$, can you tell me??

Comment: T is closed if and only if R-T is open.

Comment: @tiandiao123: Exactly!

Answer (score 3):

Consider any open cover $G_{\lambda}$ of $T$. Then if $S \subseteq G_{\lambda}$ too there is a finite covering of $S$ using sets from $G_{\lambda}$ which also contains $T$ and hence is a finite covering of $T$. Suppose $S \not \subseteq G_{\lambda}$. Then consider $ G_{\lambda} \cup T^C $ which is an open covering of $S$ since $T$ is closed and $T^C$ is an open set. Then again since $S$ is compact we have that there is a finite covering of $S$ using sets in $G_{\lambda} \cup T^C $. Removing $T^C$ if it was part of this finite covering we have a finite covering of $T$. Hence $T$ is compact.

Comment: The question was a good example of a question for which it easy to give useful hints, and probably considerably better and/or more useful than writing down the complete solution

Comment: @Julien: True. This is the first time I came across the problem too. Guess I got excited after solving it.

Comment: For those of us reading later having the whole answer spelled out is much more useful than parsing a bunch of hints. This is a Q and A site not a homework coaching site.

Comment: In Munkres's book I read something similar to " removing $T^c$ if it was part of this finite covering". However, if not removing it, it is still a finite covering of T.